# Need Access VBA to wait for Excel process to finish before resuming

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-office

I have an Access DB that has a VBA function that triggers a refresh in an Excel Workbook. The Excel Workbook is fed by a .iqy file that is hitting Oracle OBIEE.

Depending on the network traffic, the time it takes to refresh the Excel workbook varies.

I included a `pause(seconds)` function elsewhere in my VBA modules that delays further execution within a VBA function, but the problem with this is: when network traffic is fast, I unnessecarily delay the execution of VBA, because the Excel refresh is relatively fast. When the network traffic is slow, the specified number of seconds fed to `pause()` is not enough, and the program crashes.

Is there a way to get VBA to track the refresh process in Excel, and resume executing right when the process finishes?

My code so far is below:

```
Function import_tblFromIQY()

    Dim Path As String
    Path = CurrentProject.Path & "\"

    Dim rbFileName As String
    rbFileName = "dataPipeline.xls"

    ' If table tblFromIQY exists, then delete.
        If TableExists("tblFromIQY") = True Then
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblFromIQY"
            Debug.Print ">>> Deleted table tblFromIQY"
        End If

    ' Refresh linked table
        Dim appexcel As Excel.Application
        Dim wr As Excel.Workbook
        Dim wrksheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Set appexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set wr = appexcel.workbooks.Open(Path & rbFileName)
        Set wrksheet = appexcel.worksheets("Main Worksheet")

        wr.RefreshAll

        Pause (420) ' pause for 7 mins. this is approx how long it takes for the file to refresh.

        wrksheet.Rows("1:1").Select
        wrksheet.Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        wr.CheckCompatibility = False
        wr.Save
        wr.CheckCompatibility = True

        appexcel.Visible = False

        wr.Close

        Set wr = Nothing
        Set appexcel = Nothing


    ' Import Data into tblFromIQY

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, tableName:="tblFromIQY", fileName:=Path & rbFileName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True
        Debug.Print ">>> Imported data to tblFromIQY"

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of Googling, I found this solution:

```
Set wrksheet = appexcel.worksheets("Main Worksheet")
wrksheet.Range("A:BN").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Documentation on [BackgroundQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839478%28v=office.15%29.aspx).